# How to fix "no fixtures found" when installing user management system in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a database in my first Django project (called "meu_blog"). I've create a file called gerar_banco_de_dados.bat and type the following code inside:

```
python manage.py syncdb
pause
```

The code in the settings file of project "meu_blog" is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'meu_blog.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
   }
}
```

But when I tryed to create a user management system with the following information:

•Username: admin 
•E-mail: admin@gmail.com 
•Password: 1 
•Password (again): 1

I get a message saying: “no fixtures found”

[image]

When, instead, it should appear this message (according to the [tutorial book](http://www.aprendendodjango.com/) I'm following):

[image]

So, I'd like to know how to fix this "no fixtures found" and get the user management system installed.

I'm using Python 2.6 and Django 1.3.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What puzzles me is that I tried to follow the same steps of the tutorial. Therefore, I expected the screen cmd show the same things shown in the tutorial's book (where does not appear the message "No fixtures found"). But the reason may be the fact that the tutorial is a bit old (2009) and if there is no problem, it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"No fixtures found" is not an error, per se. That will often show up during syncdb if you're not using `initial_data.json` fixtures for your apps (which is not required). There is no problem.

Comment: What puzzles me is that I tried to follow the same steps of the tutorial. Therefore, I expected the screen cmd show the same things shown in the tutorial's book (where does not appear the message "No fixtures found"). But the reason may be the fact that the tutorial is a bit old (2009) and if there is no problem, it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

The user system is already installed, according to your screenshots.
The fixtures arent installed, mostly because you did not provide any.
See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures